# Angular JS, alert True or False

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I have included a checkbox, when I click on the checkbox, the alert pop up is displaying. If I click on Ok in alert pop up, than it has to replace the checkbox completely and keep true in place of that

How can we show that in Angular JS?

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('alertsMesssageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.onalertClick = function(alert) {
  var box = confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");

  if (box === false) { // yes sure
    alert.alertType = !alert.alertType;
    return true;
  }else{

  }
};
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Your question isn't really clear.

Answer (score 0):

To popup a confirmation dialog on modifying a checkbox in angular, you can do the following:

JS

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('alertsMesssageCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.alert = {
    alertType: false  //initialization
  };

  $scope.onAlertChange = function() {
    var box = confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?");

    if (box === false) { // no
      $scope.alert.alertType = !$scope.alert.alertType; //revert
    }else{ //yes sure

    }   
  };

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="alertsMesssageCtrl">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="alert.alertType" ng-change="onAlertChange()" />
</div>
```

Note that I am using `ng-change` instead of `ng-click` because it can also cover handling the checkbox ticking using the keyboard (focus to the checkbox element using Tab key and then tick it using Space bar).